# Prime factors with multiplicity

Tags: list-manipulation, factorization, version-12

This is the function I came up with:

```
Flatten[ConstantArray @@@ FactorInteger[#]] &
```

Is there a way to write this cleaner or point-free?

Update: I only have Mathematica 12 Student Edition. Seems like MapApply is new in 13.1.

**Notes on Point-Free**

Point-free style, also known as tacit programming, defines functions without reference to formal arguments. See [wikipedia: Tacit programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming), [YouTube: Point-free or Die](https://youtu.be/seVSlKazsNk). In the Wolfram Language, a point-free alternate to `f[x_] := g[h[x]]` would be `f = g @* h`. There are also some built in forms that facilitate a point-free style: `Map[f, #]&` becomes `Map[f]`; `SortBy[#, f]&` becomes `SortBy[f]`; `StringReplace[#, rules]&` becomes `StringReplace[rules]`. Mathematica provides these functions in non-curried and curried forms. Partial application is demonstrated here with the curried form. The benefit of point-free style is emphasis on function composition instead of the arguments.

Comment: What is the intended output?

Comment: What does "point-free" mean?

Comment: The function with argument 12 should return {2,2,3}. Point-free meaning without mention of the argument, just by function composition.

Comment: and other ways of combining functions like @@@.

Comment: If you have the appropriate combinators, it is ALWAYS possible to transform code into point free code. For Haskell, see https://pointfree.io/

Comment: @user1066 yes I think that works. I was just a little confused on composition `@*` versus Apply `@@`.

Comment: @lericr I edited my response to make the distinction of partial application and currying clear.

Comment: @qwr looks good!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Flatten@*MapApply[ConstantArray]@*FactorInteger
```

Comment: That’s ghastly. Gets my vote.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau actually this is almost exactly what I'm looking for. Unfortunately my Mathematica version doesn't have MapApply.

Comment: You can replace `MapApply[...]` with `Map[Apply[...]]`(see @Syed's answer for examples)

Comment: It’s a fine answer, actually. Which is the real reason it got my vote.

Answer (score 6):

For versions prior to v13.1:

```
g = Map[Apply[Sequence]]@*Map[Apply[ConstantArray]]@*FactorInteger
```

---

or

```
h = Flatten@*Map[Apply[Table]]@*FactorInteger;
```

Example:

```
g /@ Range[100, 600, 50]
```

> {{2, 2, 5, 5}, {2, 3, 5, 5}, {2, 2, 2, 5, 5}, {2, 5, 5, 5}, {2, 2, 3,
> 5, 5}, {2, 5, 5, 7}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5}, {2, 3, 3, 5, 5}, {2, 2, 5,
> 5, 5}, {2, 5, 5, 11}, {2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5}}

Answer (score 6):

```
☺ = Internal`RepetitionFromMultiplicity @* FactorInteger;

☺ @ 120
```

> ```
> {2, 2, 2, 3, 5}
> ```

```
☺☺ = MapApply[Splice @* Table] @* FactorInteger;

☺☺ @ 120
```

> ```
> {2, 2, 2, 3, 5}
> ```

Comment: I assume the Internal function isn't guaranteed stable across versions?

Answer (score 2):

This is perhaps the most obvious rewrite of your function that does not use infix operators (`@`, `@@` etc) and is a little more readable, at least to me:

````
f = Function[
      {n},
      Flatten[Apply[ConstantArray, FactorInteger[n], 1]]
    ];

f[120]

(* Out: {2, 2, 2, 3, 5} *)
```
````

Comment: but not as fancy :p

Comment: I don't think the OP was looking for ways to remove infix notation. I think OP wanted a point-free style (or a cleaner style, but since clean is subjective, I'm ignoring that). This solution still references arguments (specifically the argument named "n"), and so isn't point free.

Comment: @lericr what does "point-free" mean in this context? I'm unfamiliar with that expression.

Comment: @MarcoB "Point" is just a synonym for "argument". So, "point-free" means "no reference to arguments (as in formal arguments or placeholders, you'll obviously pass in values when you eventually want to apply your function). You typically build up a point-free implementation by starting with whatever primitive functions you have and using composition. So, instead of `f[g[#]]&` you'd use `f @* g`. Instead of `f[x_] := Sin[Sqrt[x]]` you'd use `f = Sin @* Sqrt`. "Tacit programming" is perhaps a better term. I enjoyed this video: [Point-Free or Die](https://youtu.be/seVSlKazsNk).

Comment: @MarcoB Combinators are a related idea.

Comment: @MarcoB Also, in functional programming (an undefined term that I won't try to define rigorously here) it's often convenient to have point-free representations of functions since functions are "first class objects" and you want to pass them around or map them or whatever without having to deal with managing all of the (formal) arguments.

Comment: @lericr I see. That's interesting, thank you! I'd never come across the term before. Perhaps you might consider adding your explanation to the question for clarity, or maybe a link to an explanation?

Comment: @MarcoB Added some notes.

Comment: @lericr I think the examples you gave are all curried functions, so worth mentioning

Comment: @qwr okay, but this is turning into a tutorial or something :)

Comment: @qwr Actually, I'm worried that dragging currying in could just add confusion. Are you sure it's worth it?

Comment: @qwr I went ahead and tried to add something innocuous.

Comment: @lericr the Mathematica functions have noncurried and curried forms. Fixing one argument is called partial application.

Comment: Thank you, @lericr! I've gleaned so much from reading your discussions. I believe it would be beneficial if you could incorporate this into one of your responses; it might be more informative and valuable for other users.

Comment: @qwr I was confused by your comment, but I looked back at the notes I added, and somehow I munged it up. I was perhaps doing it too late at night. Will fix...

Comment: @qwr Oh wait, you've made an edit since mine. I don't think your edit reads particularly well, but mine must not have either. Whatever--we may be beating a dead horse at this point.

Comment: @E.Chan-López Thanks! I'm not sure where else you think I should add more comments. I'm also not sure if it's specific enough to Mathematica or to the kinds of questions that come up here to warrant more commentary. But if you have more specific suggestions, I could give it a try.

Comment: Hey, @lericr! After diving into your response on the 'Prime factors with multiplicity' post, I couldn't help but think how enriching it would be if the point-free programming bit was integrated directly into the main answer. It's such a nuanced topic that, in my opinion, deserves more than just a mention in the comments.

Additionally, embedding the link to that Haskell point-free programming video within the main response might provide a clearer path for those looking to deepen their understanding. :-)

Comment: @E.Chan-López But we (myself and @qwr) have already updated the question itself.

Comment: It's true, I just saw.  It's just that I looked at the post several hours ago, but I didn't notice the update. Thanks, @leric. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
Sequence@@@ConstantArray@@@FactorInteger@120

(* {2, 2, 2, 3, 5} *)
```

Or, using [`RightComposition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RightComposition.html), where the first function called is furthest left, allowing 'normal' left-to-right reading.

```
FactorInteger/*MapApply[ConstantArray]/*MapApply[Sequence]@120

(* {2, 2, 2, 3, 5} *)
```

```
RightComposition[FactorInteger,MapApply[ConstantArray],MapApply[Sequence]]@120

(* {2, 2, 2, 3, 5} *)
```

Comment: If RightComposition is used to read left-to-right, then input 120 should be on the left. Maybe with postfix `//`?